# infinispan 9.4 - Listeners and event filter

Tags: infinispan, infinispan-9

I'm trying to use Listeners with filters in a distributed cache with two instances of Infinispan 9.4.0 and Hot Rod Client. When I try to put a new entry in cache, I get the following exception:

```
[Server:instance-one] 13:09:57,468 ERROR [stderr] (HotRod-ServerHandler-4-2) Exception in thread "HotRod-ServerHandler-4-2" org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'com.cm.broadcaster.infinispan.entity.EntityDemo' blocked by deserialization white list. Adjust the configuration serialization white list regular expression to include this class.
```

This is the cache configuration:

```
<distributed-cache name="entityCache" remote-timeout="3000" statistics-available="false">
    <memory>
        <object size="20" strategy="LRU" />
    </memory>
    <compatibility enabled="true"/>
    <file-store path="entity-store" passivation="true"/>
    <indexing index="NONE"/>
    <state-transfer timeout="60000" chunk-size="1024"/>
</distributed-cache>
```

This is my demo class:

```
public class EntityDemo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String value;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The EventFilterFactory:

```
@NamedFactory(name="entity-event-filter-factory")
public class EntityEventFilterFactory implements CacheEventFilterFactory {
    @Override
    public CacheEventFilter<String, EntityDemo> getFilter(Object[] params) {
        return new EntityEventFilter(params);
    }
}
```

The EventFilter:

```
public class EntityEventFilter implements Serializable, CacheEventFilter<String, EntityDemo> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final long filter;

    public EntityEventFilter(Object[] params) {
        this.filter = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(params[0]));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(String key, EntityDemo oldValue, Metadata oldMetadata, EntityDemo newValue, Metadata newMetadata, EventType eventType) {
        if (eventType.isCreate()) {
            if (oldValue.getId() % filter == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My test code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.addServers("localhost:11222");
RemoteCacheManager rcm = new RemoteCacheManager(cb.build());
RemoteCache<String, EntityDemo> rc = rcm.<String, 
EntityDemo>getCache("entityCache");
rc.addClientListener(new CustomListener(), new Object[]{"1"}, null);
EntityDemo e = new EntityDemo();
e.setId(1);
e.setName("Demo");
e.setValue("Demo");
rc.put("1", e);
```

The listener:

```
@ClientListener(filterFactoryName="entity-event-filter-factory")
public class CustomListener {
    @ClientCacheEntryCreated
    public void entryCreated(ClientCacheEntryCreatedEvent<String> event) {
        System.out.println("Entry created!");
        System.out.println(event.getKey());
    }
}
```

I have looked about white list for serialization, but I have found nothing.

I tried changing **object** in **memory** configuration for **binary** and disabling **compatibility**, but then I get a new exception:

```
[Server:instance-one] 13:56:42,131 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (HotRod-ServerHandler-4-2) ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand, writing keys [WrappedByteArray{bytes=[B0x01012903033E0131, hashCode=1999574342}]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.cm.broadcaster.infinispan.entity.EntityDemo
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this? Passing the -Dinfinispan.deserialization.whitelist.classes property to the server.

http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/upgrading/upgrading.html#deserialization_whitelist

Comment: Thanks! I found that information yesterday, but i didn't update my question.